# Jinja2 if/else on user defined variable

Tags: jinja2

Attempting to make a decision in a template based on the last character of a variable (third level domain hostname) , but the epiphany alludes me. Make a config stanza if value else, do the other.

I set a fact in play:

```
- name: Set third level domain name to a variable
  set_fact:
     my_3rd_levelname: "{{ ansible_nodename.split('.')[0] }}"

- name: Ascertain if which server we're on
  set_fact:
     my_one_or_two: "{{ my_3rd_levelname[-1]|int  }}"
```

...which appears to echo out with debug, save the casting as an int...see below.

```
TASK [role-test : Echo out my_one_or_two] *******************************************************************************************************************

    ok: [w.x.y.42] => {
        "my_one_or_two": "2"
    }
```

Then in the template.j2...

```
{# If my_one_or_two is even list server1 first. If not, second. #}

{% if lookup('vars,',my_one_or_two) + my_one_or_two|int is 1 %}

[some config file stanza here]

{% else %}

[some other config file stanza instead]
```

I've poked and hoped until I can stand it no longer and am reaching out.  I've tried just using the raw variable, e.g., `{% if my_one_or_two|int == 1 %}` along with many other attempts, but I'm stuck. I can't seem to overcome this error:

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got 'integer'. String: [the contents of my template]
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated at this juncture.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay...leaving this here in case someone else doesn't realize you can use any Python method  that the object supports.  Here's what I did.  Remember the server names end in 1 or 2 and its a String.

Created a varible in /roles/[rolename]/vars...

`my_simple_hostname: "{{ ansible_nodename.split('.')[0] }}"`

Then used the 'endswith' method to evaluate it....

`% if  my_simple_hostname.endswith('1') == true %}`

[content if true]

`{% else %}`

[content when false]

`{% endif %}`

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. You should take a minute to read through the formatting instructions so that you can properly format your code samples (compare the code formatting in your question from before the edit and after).